# Class not found when using PSR-4 Autoload in Linux, works in Windows

Tags: php, linux, namespaces, composer-php, psr-4

### Introduction

Hello,
I moved my files from my local pc, running WAMP to my webserver, which is a Linux machine.
I work with **composer** to use its autoload functionality to load my MVC structure, more about that later.

The error that I receive on my webpage is the following:
`Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'App\Model\DB' not found in <folder_structure>/config/_boot.php:15`

I do not have this error on my Windows machine, the code works perfectly there.

#### Folder structure

I use the same folder structure, which is (simplified) as following:

```
- config
-- _boot.php
- dist
-- index.php
-- includes
--- header.php
- src
-- app
--- Models
---- db.php
- composer.json
```

#### Code parts

My `config/_boot.php` file looks like this:

```
use App\Model\DB;
...
$db = new DB($database['host'], $database['dbname'], $database['user'], $database['password']);
```

My `src/app/Model/db.php` file looks like this:

```
namespace App\Model;
class DB
{
}
```

My `composer.json` contains this:

```
"autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/app/"
        },
        "files": [
            "src/app/functions.inc.php",
            "config/_boot.php",
            "src/app/Routing.php"
        ]
    }
```

`autoload_psr4.php`

```
return array(
    ...
    'App\\' => array($baseDir . '/src/app'),
    ...
);
```

### Question

Is there anyone who has an idea of what I am doing wrong?

#### Things I have tried / Checked

- Check the folder permissions
- I tried adding `"App\\Model\\": "src/app/Model/"` to my `composer.json` as well

PS: This is my first question on Stackoverflow, tips on improving the layout are welcome...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[PSR-4](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) states:

> The terminating class name corresponds to a file name ending in .php.
>   The file name MUST match the case of the terminating class name.

You have broken this rule by placing `DB` class into `db.php` file. The reason it works on Windows and not on Linux is that the later is case-sensitive regarding file and folder names.

So the fix is to rename `db.php` into `DB.php`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have now renamed the file to DB.php, but it still does not work. Do you have any other suggestion?
Should I place the whole `"App\\Model\\"`: in my composer.json?

Comment: Indeed, I still have the same error. `Class 'App\Model\DB' not found`

Comment: `$ ls src/app/Model` -->
`Alert.php  CalenderActivity.php  Category.php  DB.php  Leader.php  Parsedown.php  Registration.php  User.php`

Comment: @GodOfNeoN, have you called `composer dump-autoload` command to regenerate the autoload files?

Comment: I did perform that command yes.
The result is - just like above in the question - that I have this in the generated file (`vendor/composer/autoload_psr4.php`): ``'App\\' => array($baseDir . '/src/app'),``

Comment: I should be punching myself...
You did indeed solve my problem.
I tested something out with another namespace name, and forgot to change that

Comment: @GodOfNeoN, glad to help